# Why does avg throw an error?

Tags: sql-server

I have a `table` called `tblFilterSum` and its `primary key` is `SumID`. Another `table` is `tblFilterProd` and its `primary key` is `ProdID`. Between the two there is an n:m relation, represented by the `table` `tblFilterProdsInSum` which has a two-dimensional `primary key` of `(SumID, ProdID)`. Unfortunately, `SumID` and `ProdID` were not `foreign keys`, therefore I modified the schema to make `SumID` a `foreign key`, which `references tblFilterSum(SumID)` and `ProdID` another `foreign key`, which `references` `tblFilterProd(ProdID)`. I have added a descending index to `tblFilterProdsInSum` for `SumID` and another descending index for `ProdID`. Now I intend to measure the speed of selection and I have written the following script:

```
declare @start datetime;
set @start = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
declare @index int;
set @index = 0;
while (@index < 1000)
begin
select avg(tblFilterProdsInSum.SumID + tblFilterProdsInSum.ProdID)
from tblFilterSum
join tblFilterProdsInSum
on tblFilterSum.SumID = tblFilterProdsInSum.SumID
join tblFilterProd
on tblFilterProdsInSum.ProdID = tblFilterProd.ProdID
set @index = @index + 1;
end
declare @end datetime;
set @end = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
select @start, @end, @end - @start;
```

This throws the following error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

Both `SumID` and `ProdID` are of `int` type. I wonder what is the cause of this error. Is SQL Server adding all values and then dividing with the `count`?

Comment: Based on the exception the result of adding SumID and ProdID is probably outside the range of int data type (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx). So what are the values of SumID in ProdID in this case?

Comment: They are large integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can re-cast one of your factors to avoid the numeric overflow

```
select avg(cast(tblFilterProdsInSum.SumID as float) + tblFilterProdsInSum.ProdID)
```

Comment: @LajosArpad Been bit by that dog myself.  :)

Comment: @LajosArpad Considering you have such large integers, you may want to consider BIGINT for these fields.

Comment: That schema change might be done when the values are getting close to overflow. The maximum value of int is 2,147,483,647 and my maximum is of a scale of millions, which makes me wonder about the things happening under the hood. Is SQL Server adding the values and dividing at the end? If so, why is the error not appearing when I convert an operand to float?

Comment: @LajosArpad  You are correct,the max value of an int is 2.14B.  I suspect the sum of two large INTs over many records forced the overflow.  Just curios what is the sum(cast(tblFilterProdsInSum.SumID as float) + tblFilterProdsInSum.ProdID)

Comment: 10563208270. Off course this cannot be stored into an int, but if the system under the hood would detect that an overflow is imminent, the average could be calculated as several averages accompanied by multiplicators under the hood. This is clearly not the case in SQL server avg having an integer as parameter. If I run with avg(tblFilterProdsInSum.ProdID), I get the same error as in the question.

Comment: I suppose under the hood avg(foo) = sum(foo) / count(foo). That would explain the error.